# How to Efficiently Download One Million Images with R and Fully Utilize Computer/Network Resources

Tags: r, performance, image-processing, download, parallel-processing

I am attempting to download data consisting of approximately 1 million jpg files for which I have individual URL's and desired file names. The images have a mean filesize of approximately 120KB and range from 1KB to 1MB. I would like to use R to download the images.

I've tried a few things and eventually figured out a way that has let me download all million images in under three hours. My current strategy works, but it is a somewhat absurd solution that I would prefer not to use ever again, and I'm baffled as to why it even works. I would like to understand what's going on and to find a more elegant and efficient way of achieving the same result.

I started out with mapply and download.file() but this only managed a rate of 2 images per second. Next, I parallelized the process with the parallel package. This was very effective and improved the rate to 9 images per second. I assumed that would be the most I could achieve, but I noticed that the resources being used by my modest laptop were nowhere near capacity. I checked to make sure there wasn't a significant disk or network access bottleneck, and sure enough, neither were experiencing much more than ~10% of their capacity.

So I split up the url information and opened a new R console window where I ran a second instance of the same script on a different segment of the data to achieve 18 images per second. Then I just continued to open more and more instances, giving each of them a unique section of the full list of URL's. It was not until I had 12 open that there was any hint of slowing down. Each instance actually gave a nearly linear increase in downloads per second, and with some memory management, I approached my maximum down speed of 13 MB/s.

I have attached a graph showing the [approximate total images being downloaded per second as a function of the number of instances running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eKL6.png)

Also attached is a screenshot of my resource monitor while [10 simultaneous instances of R were running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgHLw.png)

I find this result very surprising and I don't quite understand why this should be possible. What's making each individual script run so slowly? If the computer can run 12 instances of this code with little to no diminishing returns, what prevents it from just running 12 times as fast? Is there a way to achieve the same thing without having to open up entirely new R environments?

Here is the code I am asking about specifically. Unfortunately I cannot disclose the original URL's but the script is nearly identical to what I am using. I have replaced my data with a few CC images from wikimedia. For better replication, please replace "images" with your own large URL list if you have access to such a thing.

```
library(parallel)
library(data.table)

images <-
    data.table(
        file = c(
            "Otter.jpg",
            "Ocean_Ferret.jpg",
            "Aquatic_Cat.jpg",
            "Amphibious_Snake_Dog.jpg"
        ),
        url = c(
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Otter_and_Bamboo_Wall_%2822222758789%29.jpg/640px-Otter_and_Bamboo_Wall_%2822222758789%29.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f7/Otter_Looking_Back_%2817939094316%29.jpg/640px-Otter_Looking_Back_%2817939094316%29.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Otter1_%2814995327039%29.jpg/563px-Otter1_%2814995327039%29.jpg",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/Otter_Profile_%2817962452452%29.jpg/640px-Otter_Profile_%2817962452452%29.jpg"
        ) #full URL's are redundant and unnecessary but I kept them in case there was some performance advantage over nesting a function inside download.file that combines strings.

    )

#Download with Mapply (just for benchmarking, not actually used in the script)
system.time(
    mapply(
        function(x, y)
            download.file(x, y, mode = 'wb', quiet = TRUE),
        x = images$url,
        y = images$file,
        SIMPLIFY = "vector",
        USE.NAMES = FALSE
    ) 
)


#Parallel Download with clusterMap (this is what each instance is running. I give each instance a different portion of the images data table)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())

system.time(
    clusterMap(
        cl,
        download.file,
        url = images$url,
        destfile = images$file,
        quiet = TRUE,
        mode = 'wb',
        .scheduling = 'dynamic', 
        SIMPLIFY = 'vector',
        USE.NAMES = FALSE
    )
)
```

In summary, the questions I am asking are:

1) Why is my solution behaving this way? More specifically, why is 1 script not fully utilizing my computer's resources?

2) What is a better way to achieve the following with R: download 120GB composed of one million jpeg images directly via their URL's in under 3 hours.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
> ```

This line says to make a backend cluster with a number of nodes equal to your cores. That would probably be 2, 4 or 8, depending on how beefy a machine you have.

Since, as you noticed, the downloading process isn't CPU-bound, there's nothing stopping you from making the cluster as big as you want. Replace that line with something like

```
cl <- makeCluster(50)
```

and you'll have 50 R sessions downloading in parallel. Increase the number until you hit your bandwidth or memory limit.

Comment: Thank you, this makes everything so much simpler. Do you have any idea what is keeping the download process for each node so slow?